# NETWORK SERVICE permission for database

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am just wondering is it good idea to give NETWORK SERVICE permission for MSSQL database, can it open any security holes? Then I don't need to set any login parameters in my web app(ASP.NET MVC) config file, I go with integrated permission.

Answer (score 1):

[Looking at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684272%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), Windows Network Service Account has minimum privileges in windows and it acts as the computer on the network.

But I personally believe that, if you are using it for personal development then it is ok to use network service to access database (if they are on same machine). You might need to configure application pool of your web app to use that service as well in order to have your web app authenticated by SQL Server.

But if it is for enterprise, then I would suggest you to create a separate domain account and use that domain account for both SQL Server and Web App. In that way you will have more better control over that account and it's permissions and less chances to find out that you have given more than required permissions to some default windows account.